# .NET Framework 4.0: Chaining tasks in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task

I want to chain multiple `Task`s, so that when one ends the next one starts. I know I can do this using `ContinueWith`. But what if I have a large number of tasks, so that:

> t1 continues with t2
>
> t2 continues with t3
>
> t3 continues with t4
>
> ...

Is there a nice way to do it, other than creating this chain manually using a loop?

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you would use ContinueWith?  That might spark some more feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, assuming you have some sort of enumerable of `Action` delegates or something you want to do, you can easily use LINQ to do the following:

```
// Create the base task.  Run synchronously.
var task = new Task(() => { });
task.RunSynchronously();

// Chain them all together.
var query = 
    // For each action
    from action in actions

    // Assign the task to the continuation and
    // return that.
    select (task = task.ContinueWith(action));

// Get the last task to wait on.
// Note that this cannot be changed to "Last"
// because the actions enumeration could have no
// elements, meaning that Last would throw.
// That means task can be null, so a check
// would have to be performed on it before
// waiting on it (unless you are assured that
// there are items in the action enumeration).
task = query.LastOrDefault();
```

The above code is really your loop, just in a fancier form.  It does the same thing in that it takes the previous task (after primed with a dummy "noop" `Task`) and then adds a continuation in the form of `ContinueWith` (assigning the continuation to the current task in the process for the next iteration of the loop, which is performed when `LastOrDefault` is called).

Answer (score 3):

You may use static extensions `ContinueWhenAll` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362175.aspx).

So you can pass multiple tasks.

---

### Update

You can use a chaining extension such as this:

```
public static class MyTaskExtensions
{
    public static Task BuildChain(this Task task, 
        IEnumerable<Action<Task>> actions)
    {
        if (!actions.Any())
            return task;
        else
        {
            Task continueWith = task.ContinueWith(actions.First());
            return continueWith.BuildChain(actions.Skip(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aliostad: I don't think that's the answer, since they are all dependent on the previous one being completed (t3 depends on t2, t2 depends on t1, etc).

Comment: Yes, but I imagine you can do tasks in batches so each in one batch.

Comment: @Aliostad: That doesn't make sense; there is a clear dependency on each previous task that the OP defined, waiting on all of them and then continuing would have a completely different effect.

Comment: @Aliostad: I've formatted your code for more readability, but I've also changed the line `if (actions.Count() == 0)` to `if (!actions.Any())` as `Count() == 0` (or `Count() != 0)`) is a [bad idea](http://caspershouse.com/post/Anything-Counts.aspx)

Comment: @Aliostad:  There's another problem with the code above.  You are passing `actions.Skip(1)` for each recursive iteration.  This causes the enumeration to be evaluated from the beginning each time, causing the number of operations equal to the summation of `N` (i.e `N + (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 1`.  For a large `N` this can have a big performance impact (not to mention the stacks generated because of recursion).  I'd strongly recommend that you revisit that approach.

Comment: Hi @CasperOne. This code was meant to illustrate the point. I did not write it with the intention to make it performant - it was just to inspire Ilya on alternative approaches. But thanks again for pointing it out.